# CKEDITOR.editor.on not working with replaceAll

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to capture an event from a plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function( ) {
    CKEDITOR.replaceAll( 'js-ckeditor' );

    CKEDITOR.editor.on('simpleuploads.startUpload', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev.data)
    });
});
```

...but when I run it, I see the error `TypeError: CKEDITOR.editor.on is not a function`. What am I doing wrong here? According to the documentation editor should have a method "on" (which I can see when I inspect the object). By the way, both the textarea and plugin function well so replaceAll seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CKEDITOR.editor.on` is a method of a working editor instance, i.e. returned by [`CKEDITOR.replace`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace), while [`CKEDITOR.editor`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor) is just editor constructor.

Instead attach [`CKEDITOR.instanceReady`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady) event before `CKEDITOR.replaceAll` and use event data to attach more events to particular editor instances:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    evt.editor.on( 'simpleuploads.startUpload', function( evt ) {
        ...
    } );
} );

CKEDITOR.replaceAll( 'js-ckeditor' );
```